# Ubuntu 18.04 and ethernet connection

Tags: 18.04, internet, ethernet

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 today but I can't use the internet.

But Ubuntu 18.04 does recognize that the ethernet cable is connected. When I go to the Settings - Network, it says 'Ethernet (enp3s0) Connected - 100Mb/s' and 'Ethernet (enp4s0) Cable unplugged'.

I know people have asked questions like this with what the 'ifconfig' command printed in cmd. However, I can't download ifconfig since there is not internet connection in the first place. In this case, is the problem a hardware problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  The command `ifconfig` is old & deprecated.  Refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html.en for some help with `ip` which replaced it many years ago.

Comment: @Peter probably not. does the problem persist with ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: Can you try by powering down your computer, disconnecting Ethernet cable, powering back up, and then reconnecting the cable?